# Grafana - filter series

Tags: grafana

Is there an option to filter series in a Time series graph by:

1. selecting only a number of series with greatest average values and discarding others?
2. discarding series whose average values have not reached a certain threshold

For example here only purple, green and yellow should be shown while others removed both from the graph and legend.
[image]

Comment: can You show screen with editor of this widget? (click header, then click "Edit")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find an option to filter data.
So I would suggest to change the query in a way that versions 3.9.0, 3.10.0 and 3.11.0 will be returned only.